# Ending position out of bounds: 18

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, string

I have a Custom Edit button. When clicking the Edit it is showing the error as "Ending position out of bounds: 18" Below is the code for class.Thanks

```
public with sharing class ICA_Relatepart_Rel_editController {
    Private RelatedParties__c objRPID{get;set;}
    Private id policyPl;
    Private id ACCid ;
    Private Integer i;
    Private string IsFrom;
    Private RelatedParties__c Relapar;
    Private String retURL;
    Private PageReference pageref;
    public Boolean b2{get;set;}

    public ICA_Relatepart_Rel_editController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        Relapar= new RelatedParties__c();
        Relapar= (RelatedParties__c)controller.getrecord();
        retURL= ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
        System.debug('retURL======='+retURL);
        if(retURL!= null){
            i = retURL.lastindexof('?id=');
            System.debug('i======='+i);  
            //retURL = retURL.replace('/','');
            retURL = retURL.substring(i+4,i+19);
            pageref=null;
        }
    }
    public Pagereference route(){
        String opportunityKeyPrefix = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        String prolineKeyPrefix = Product_Line__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        String policyPlanKeyPrefix = PolicyPlan__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        String AccountKeyPrefix = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        String Relatedparties= RelatedParties__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        PolicyPlan__c policyplan =new PolicyPlan__c (); 
        RelatedParties__c Relpar=new RelatedParties__c();

        Relpar= [Select id, Policy_Plan_number__c, Product_Line__c, Opportunity__c from RelatedParties__c where id =:Relapar.id ] ;
        policyPl = [Select id, Policy_Plan_number__c from RelatedParties__c where id=:Relapar.id].Policy_Plan_number__c  ;
        ACCid=[Select id, Related_Account__c,RelatedPartiestoAccount__c from RelatedParties__c where id =:Relapar.id ].RelatedPartiestoAccount__c ;

        if(String.valueOf(policyPl) !=null && String.valueOf(policyPl) != '' ){
            policyplan = [Select id, Confirmed__c,Related_Opportunity__c from PolicyPlan__c  where id =:policyPl ]; 
        }

        if(String.valueOf(retURL).startsWith(policyPlanKeyPrefix)){
            if(String.valueOf(policyPl) !=null && String.valueOf(policyPl) != ''){
                if(policyplan.Confirmed__c == true){
                    b2=true;
                }else{
                    IsFrom='Policy';
                    string RPL='1';
                    pageref = new PageReference('/apex/ICAProductLIne?Relapar='+Relapar.id+'&Policy_Plan_number__c='+Relpar.Policy_Plan_number__c+'&IsFrom='+IsFrom +'&RPL='+RPL+'&OppId='+'xx');
                    pageref.setRedirect(true);
                    return pageRef;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(String.valueOf(retURL).startsWith(opportunityKeyPrefix)){
            If(Relpar.Product_Line__c!=null){
                IsFrom ='EDITPROLINE';
                objRPID =[Select id,Opportunity__c,Related_Account__c,Product_Line__c from RelatedParties__c where id=: Relapar.Id];
                PageReference pageref= new PageReference('/apex/ProdLineCheckPage?retURL=%2f'+Relpar.Opportunity__c+'&id='+ objRPID.Product_Line__c);
                pageref.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;  
            }
        }
        else if(String.valueOf(retURL).startsWith(AccountKeyPrefix) || String.valueOf(retURL).startsWith(Relatedparties)){
            if(Relpar.Policy_Plan_number__c!=null){
                //Redirect to policy related party edit page
                if(String.valueOf(policyPl) !=null && String.valueOf(policyPl) != ''){
                    if(policyplan.Confirmed__c == true ){
                        b2=true;
                    }
                    else{
                        IsFrom='Policy';
                        string RPL='1';
                        pageref = new PageReference('/apex/ICAProductLIne?Relapar='+Relapar.id+'&Policy_Plan_number__c='+Relpar.Policy_Plan_number__c+'&IsFrom='+IsFrom +'&RPL='+RPL+'&OppId='+'xx');
                        pageref.setRedirect(true);
                        return pageRef;
                    }
                }
            }
            else If(Relpar.Product_Line__c!=null){
                //Redirect to product line edit page 
                IsFrom ='EDITPROLINE';
                objRPID =[Select id,Opportunity__c,Related_Account__c,Product_Line__c from RelatedParties__c where id=: Relapar.Id];
                PageReference pageref= new PageReference('/apex/ProdLineCheckPage?retURL=%2f'+Relpar.Opportunity__c +'&id='+ objRPID.Product_Line__c);
                pageref.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;  
            }
            else{
                //Redirect to
                pageref = new PageReference('/apex/ICAProductLIne?TrustAccount='+ACCid +'&Relapar='+Relapar.id+'&OppId='+'xx');
                pageref.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;
            }
        }
        else if(String.valueOf(retURL).startsWith(prolineKeyPrefix)){
            IsFrom ='EDITPROLINE';
            objRPID =[Select id,Opportunity__c,Related_Account__c,Product_Line__c from RelatedParties__c where id=: Relapar.Id];
            PageReference pageref= new PageReference('/apex/ProdLineCheckPage?retURL=%2f'+Relpar.Opportunity__c+'&id='+ objRPID.Product_Line__c);
            pageref.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;  
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference BacktoAccount(){
        PageReference pageRef  = new PageReference('/' + retURL);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your posts will be much better received by the community if you put some work into removing irrelevant code. Most of this code has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your debug is showing 'i=======-1'.Which meand "?id" wasn't found on your retURL. That makes your substring call to fail.